# M2E setting file

Tags: maven, m2e

I just have installed M2E for my Eclipse IDE, I'd like to know how to create a setting file, which can be used to config maven for eclipse, contains infomation such as remote repository, etc. Whether I need to download maven and set maven_home to do that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Eclipse go to: Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installation: select a file (your settings.xml) for global settings for the embedded installation. The file can be located everywhere you want (the .m2 repository folder is a good location) and must fit the settings.xml style you can find in the documentation.